# why am i getting this outlook rules error

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

i am trying to add a rule and i get the following error:

**One or more rules cannot be uploaded to microsoft exchange and have been deactivated.  this could be because some of the parameters are not supported or there is insufficient space to store all of the rules.**

could microsoft give me a more vague error message?  why can't it tell me exactly what is wrong here ??

Comment: Can you post your rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you ran out of space for rules. There is a limit in Exchange to how much space the rules can take per mail account.

Quote from an answer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.outlook.general&tid=3db4aecf-24c2-450b-a926-a27a6e994ca8&cat=en_US_31ae1f62-930c-4298-b074-3f017f7df8c5&lang=en&cr=US&sloc=&p=1):

> There is a size limit for the rules, not a an amount limit. The limit is in
>   Exchange and not in Outlook. Exchange 2003 and previous have a limit of
>   32KB. Exchange 2007 has a default limit of 64KB but this can be extended to
>   256KB by your mail admin.

More info and suggestion about what to do [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241325) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886616).

Comment: why would they put a size limit on rules.  when you say 64k, how big is a rule ?

Comment: No idea why. I for example don't really have many rules and I also ran out of space. In the links there's a few things MS recommends to do in order to reduce rules size, perhaps try some and see if it makes any difference. I just removed the rules I didn't really need.